# Does going directly from QPR Beta-> major Android Beta (without going to stable in between) would force a wipe in between or not?

Tags: ota-update, android-beta-program

Others have asked elsewhere, so I'm looking for answers for them.

Does anyone recollect from a year ago what the experience was if you're either on or opted into the Google Pixel Android 12 QPR program, and you opted into the Android 13 Beta 1, did you get an OTA directly from QPR Beta to 13 Beta 1?

For now, I've been advising users to opt out of the QPR2 Beta, but don't take the OTA until the Stable QPR2 one comes for their device and then once on that, opt into the Android 14 Beta 1 when it's available, just to be safe.

I'm aware the Android 13 QPR2 has gone Stable for all appropriate Pixel phones, except for all the Pixel 6 series, which I've heard will arrive on March 20, but that's third-hand information.

I don't know if a QPR Beta -> major Android Beta (without going to stable in between) would force a wipe in between or not.  We all know it hopefully "shouldn't", but I'm looking for someone who knows for sure.

Thanks!